# How to Change Colors of a Company Logo without Using Pen Tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, logo

[image: Hydro Company Logo]

I have a couple of company logos that I want to change to color white (to be placed in a black background). This logo is pretty simple enough to just use the pen tool. However, I have some logos that are complex as this one below:

[image: outokumpu company logo]

What's the best way of changing these colors with minimal pain? Other solutions that I found is to **Recolor with Preset** in the **Edit** action, but that option is greyed out and cannot be used. Please help me out! The struggle is real.

Comment: Do you have the working file or are you working off a jpg/png/gif?

Comment: Hey AndrewH! I am working off a png and jpg files.

Comment: With raster images it comes down to masking, desaturating, inverting, and levels/curves adjustments (if desired) most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because these are raster images your best bet is to either:

1) Re-create the image to easily change the colors.

or

2) Bring the images into a photo editor program and change the hue/saturation. There are also plenty of other color changing methods in Photoshop if that is the program you plan to be using.

- Color Balance
- Selective Color

If you just want to change the text color (If you do not have the original font) in illustrator that would be much easier. Just go to Object -> Live Trace -> Make. This would work entirely for the first image (font & graphic, however using the pen tool will most likely give better results). The second image you would need the text part of the image as its own separate file.

Comment: Found an easy fix! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vaOyLaBaqcE

Comment: @sylvee if that solution is acceptable then I am happy you found a solution. Just make sure to desaturate the logo first. You can also use a photo filter layer adjustment. There are plenty of ways to change a color of a jpg.

Answer (score 0):

I can't yet comment on AndrewH's response, because I just got my account, but I would agree that the best way to change the first logo would be to open it in Adobe Illustrator and use the Live Trace/Image Trace tool. There is no "simple" solution for the second, well at least as simple as the first, but a lot of playing around in Photoshop will hopefully get you close. Here is a simple video to get you started:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=argiGgAD0Ck

Answer (score 0):

I know with JPEGS all of the 'Edit Colors' options are grayed out until they are embedded within the project in the Creative Cloud version of Illustrator. It is a major bug that Adobe has yet to correct for some unknown reason.